# Custom keyboard for iOS

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, keyboard

I've built keyboard this way. (code below)

But, there are some problems like:

- when you click on some button, it's click animation taking long to get back.
- there is no way to place some common keys as globe symbol for language changing or caps lock

What I want to do is, to modify original iOS keyboard and add some other buttons.

Is it possible? Any suggestions?

```
import UIKit

class KeyboardViewController: UIInputViewController {

    @IBOutlet var nextKeyboardButton: UIButton!

    override func updateViewConstraints() {
        super.updateViewConstraints()

        // Add custom view sizing constraints here
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let buttonTitles1 = ["Q", "W", "E", "R", "T", "Y", "U", "I", "O", "P"]
        let buttonTitles2 = ["A", "S", "D", "F", "G", "H", "J", "K", "L"]
        let buttonTitles3 = ["CP", "Z", "X", "C", "V", "B", "N", "M", "BP"]
        let buttonTitles4 = ["CHG", "SPACE", "RETURN"]

        var row1 = createRowOfButtons(buttonTitles1)
        var row2 = createRowOfButtons(buttonTitles2)
        var row3 = createRowOfButtons(buttonTitles3)
        var row4 = createRowOfButtons(buttonTitles4)

        self.view.addSubview(row1)
        self.view.addSubview(row2)
        self.view.addSubview(row3)
        self.view.addSubview(row4)

        row1.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
        row2.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
        row3.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
        row4.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)

        addConstraintsToInputView(self.view, rowViews: [row1, row2, row3, row4])
    }

    func createRowOfButtons(buttonTitles: [NSString]) -> UIView {

        var buttons = [UIButton]()
        var keyboardRowView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50))

        for buttonTitle in buttonTitles{

            let button = createButtonWithTitle(buttonTitle)
            buttons.append(button)
            keyboardRowView.addSubview(button)
        }

        addIndividualButtonConstraints(buttons, mainView: keyboardRowView)

        return keyboardRowView
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated
    }

    override func textWillChange(textInput: UITextInput) {
        // The app is about to change the document's contents. Perform any preparation here.
    }

    override func textDidChange(textInput: UITextInput) {
        // The app has just changed the document's contents, the document context has been updated.

        var textColor: UIColor
        var proxy = self.textDocumentProxy as UITextDocumentProxy
        if proxy.keyboardAppearance == UIKeyboardAppearance.Dark {
            textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        } else {
            textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        }
    }



    func createButtonWithTitle(title: String) -> UIButton {

        let button = UIButton.buttonWithType(.System) as UIButton
        button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 20)
        button.setTitle(title, forState: .Normal)
        button.sizeToFit()
        button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(15)
        button.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)
        button.setTitleColor(UIColor.darkGrayColor(), forState: .Normal)

        button.addTarget(self, action: "didTapButton:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

        return button
    }

    func didTapButton(sender: AnyObject?) {

        let button = sender as UIButton
        var proxy = textDocumentProxy as UITextDocumentProxy

        if let title = button.titleForState(.Normal) {
            switch title {
            case "BP" :
                proxy.deleteBackward()
            case "RETURN" :
                proxy.insertText("\n")
            case "SPACE" :
                proxy.insertText(" ")
            case "CHG" :
                self.advanceToNextInputMode()
            default :
                proxy.insertText(title)
            }
        }
    }

    func addIndividualButtonConstraints(buttons: [UIButton], mainView: UIView){

        for (index, button) in enumerate(buttons) {

            var topConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: button, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: mainView, attribute: .Top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 1)

            var bottomConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: button, attribute: .Bottom, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: mainView, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: -1)

            var rightConstraint : NSLayoutConstraint!

            if index == buttons.count - 1 {

                rightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: button, attribute: .Right, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: mainView, attribute: .Right, multiplier: 1.0, constant: -1)

            }else{

                let nextButton = buttons[index+1]
                rightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: button, attribute: .Right, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nextButton, attribute: .Left, multiplier: 1.0, constant: -1)
            }


            var leftConstraint : NSLayoutConstraint!

            if index == 0 {

                leftConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: button, attribute: .Left, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: mainView, attribute: .Left, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 1)

            }else{

                let prevtButton = buttons[index-1]
                leftConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: button, attribute: .Left, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: prevtButton, attribute: .Right, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 1)

                let firstButton = buttons[0]
                var widthConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: firstButton, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: button, attribute: .Width, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)

                widthConstraint.priority = 800
                mainView.addConstraint(widthConstraint)
            }

            mainView.addConstraints([topConstraint, bottomConstraint, rightConstraint, leftConstraint])
        }
    }


    func addConstraintsToInputView(inputView: UIView, rowViews: [UIView]){

        for (index, rowView) in enumerate(rowViews) {
            var rightSideConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: rowView, attribute: .Right, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: inputView, attribute: .Right, multiplier: 1.0, constant: -1)

            var leftConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: rowView, attribute: .Left, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: inputView, attribute: .Left, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 1)

            inputView.addConstraints([leftConstraint, rightSideConstraint])

            var topConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint

            if index == 0 {
                topConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: rowView, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: inputView, attribute: .Top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)

            }else{

                let prevRow = rowViews[index-1]
                topConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: rowView, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: prevRow, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)

                let firstRow = rowViews[0]
                var heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: firstRow, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: rowView, attribute: .Height, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)

                heightConstraint.priority = 800
                inputView.addConstraint(heightConstraint)
            }
            inputView.addConstraint(topConstraint)

            var bottomConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint

            if index == rowViews.count - 1 {
                bottomConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: rowView, attribute: .Bottom, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: inputView, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)

            }else{

                let nextRow = rowViews[index+1]
                bottomConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: rowView, attribute: .Bottom, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nextRow, attribute: .Top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
            }

            inputView.addConstraint(bottomConstraint)
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the github repo below. It's nearly 1:1 immitation of iOS 8 original keyboard and works like a charm

https://github.com/archagon/tasty-imitation-keyboard

Answer (score 3):

## when you click on some button, it's click animation taking long to get back.

Your keys are nothing more than [`UIButton`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/index.html)s. The fade-out animation you're seeing is the normal animation for a `UIButton`—you can see it for yourself on most buttons across the system. Instead of initializing it with `UIButtonType.System`, use `.Custom` and set your own appearance for the desired states.

As an example (there are many possibilities):

```
let button = UIButton(.Custom)
button.setTitleColor(UIColor.redColor(), forState: .Highlighted)
```

Note that you don't even have to restrict yourself to using `UIButton`—custom keyboards are a blank slate.

## there is no way to place some common keys as globe symbol for language changing or caps lock

From the [Custom Keyboard Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Keyboard.html):

> The system picks the appropriate “next” keyboard; there is no API to
>   obtain a list of enabled keyboards or for picking a particular
>   keyboard to switch to.

So these "special" keys are also up to you to provide, most likely with your own custom icons. If you're using `UIButton`, that probably means calling `setImage:forState:`. It looks like most third-party keyboards use a globe icon almost identicial to the system one for the "next" key.

**There is no API to mod the system keyboard—you must build one yourself from the ground-up.**

Answer (score 2):

For slow animation, you can study these github repo on how they do their animation:

1. https://github.com/YuAo/WUEmoticonsKeyboard (See the popview when the button gets pressed.)
2. https://github.com/ayushgoel/AGEmojiKeyboard
3. https://github.com/kulpreetchilana/Custom-iOS-Keyboards
4. or search github:https://github.com/search?utf8=✓&q=iOS+keyboard

Note: They are mostly objective-c repo.

Lastly, it might be cheaper to install a custom keyboard than to make one: 
http://www.imore.com/best-custom-keyboards-ios-8